# sort a list of numbers by their 'visual similarity'

Tags: sorting, haskell

consider a function, which rates the level of 'visual similarity' between two numbers: 666666 and 666166 would be very similar, unlike 666666 and 111111

```
type N = Int
type Rate = Int

similar :: N -> N -> Rate
similar a b = length . filter id . zipWith (==) a' $ b'
  where a' = show a
        b' = show b

similar 666666 666166
--> 5
-- high rate : very similar

similar 666666 111111
--> 0
-- low rate : not similar
```

There will be more sophisticated implementations for this, however this serves the purpose.

The intention is to find a function that sorts a given list of N's, so that each item is the most similar one to it's preceding item. Since the first item does not have a predecessor, there must be a given first N.

```
similarSort :: N -> [N] -> [N]
```

Let's look at some sample data: They don't need to have the same arity but it makes it easier to reason about it.

```
sample :: [N]
sample = [2234, 8881, 1222, 8888, 8822, 2221, 5428]
```

one could be tempted to implement the function like so:

```
similarSortWrong x xs = reverse . sortWith (similar x) $ xs
```

but this would lead to a wrong result:

```
similarSortWrong 2222 sample
--> [2221,1222,8822,2234,5428,8888,8881]
```

In the beginning it looks correct, but it's obvious that 8822 should rather be followed by 8881, since it's more similar that 2234.

So here's the implementation I came up with:

```
similarSort _ [] = []
similarSort x xs = x : similarSort a as
  where (a:as) = reverse . sortWith (similar x) $ xs

similarSort 2222 sample
--> [2222,2221,2234,1222,8822,8888,8881]
```

It seems to work. but it also seems to do lot more more work than necessary. Every step the whole rest is sorted again, just to pick up the first element. Usually lazyness should allow this, but `reverse` might break this again. I'd be keen to hear, if someone know if there's a common abstraction for this problem.

Comment: 1. Instead of `reverse . sortWith` use `sortBy (\a b -> compare (similar x b) (similar x a))` so that you sort the list in the right order and don't have to reverse it. 2. Instead of sorting at all just use `minBy` or `maxBy` which has much better performance and is sufficient for your problem.

Comment: the first thing looks logical to me: When using `sortBy (flip compare \`on\` similar x)` it's already much faster. With the second propose, I'm not sure yet. Because beside the maximum/minimum I need also the list with the selected element removed...

Comment: You are right of course. Still sorting is unnecessary. Consider writing your own function, that walks the list remembering the minimum element and if it finds a smaller element it "replaces" that element and returns a pair of the minimum element and the remainder.

Comment: I'm not sure that the definition you gave is well-defined. I mean: in order for sorting to make sense you must define a linear order, and I'm not at all sure that your `similar` defines one...

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. In your last result, `[2222,2221,2234,1222,8822,8888,8881]`, e.g. 2221 should actually be followed by 2222, since that is the number that is most similar to it. You cannot define a [linear order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_theory#Basic_definitions) using your similarity function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's relatively straightforward to implement the greedy algorithm you ask for. Let's start with some boilerplate; we'll use the [`these`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/these) package for a `zip`-like that hands us the "unused" tail ends of zipped-together lists:

```
import Data.Align
import Data.These
sampleStart = "2222"
sampleNeighbors = ["2234", "8881", "1222", "8888", "8822", "2221", "5428"]
```

Instead of using numbers, I'll use lists of digits -- just so we don't have to litter the code with conversions between the form that's convenient for the user and the form that's convenient for the algorithm. You've been a bit fuzzy about how to rate the similarity of two digit strings, so let's make it as concrete as possible: any digits that differ cost 1, and if the digit strings vary in length we have to pay 1 for each extension to the right. Thus:

```
distance :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Int
distance l r = sum $ alignWith elemDistance l r where
    elemDistance (These l r) | l == r = 0
    elemDistance _ = 1
```

A handy helper function will pick the smallest element of some list (by a user-specified measure) and return the rest of the list in some implementation-defined order.

```
minRestOn :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> Maybe (a, [a])
minRestOn f [] = Nothing
minRestOn f (x:xs) = Just (go x [] xs) where
    go min rest [] = (min, rest)
    go min rest (x:xs) = if f x < f min
                         then go x (min:rest) xs
                         else go min (x:rest) xs
```

Now the greedy algorithm almost writes itself:

```
greedy :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
greedy here neighbors = here : case minRestOn (distance here) neighbors of
    Nothing -> []
    Just (min, rest) -> greedy min rest
```

We can try it out on your sample:

```
> greedy sampleStart sampleNeighbors
["2222","1222","2221","2234","5428","8888","8881","8822"]
```

Just eyeballing it, that seems to do okay. However, as with many greedy algorithms, this one only minimizes the *local* cost of each edge in the path. If you want to minimize the *total* cost of the path found, you need to use another algorithm. For example, we can pull in the [`astar`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/astar-0.3.0.0/docs/Data-Graph-AStar.html) package. For simplicity, I'm going to do everything in a very inefficient way, but it's not too hard to do it "right". We'll need a fair chunk more imports:

```
import Data.Graph.AStar
import Data.Hashable
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe
import qualified Data.HashSet as HS
```

Unlike before, where we only wanted the nearest neighbor, we'll now want all the neighbors. (Actually, we could probably implement the previous use of `minRestOn` using the following function and `minimumOn` or something. Give it a try if you're interested!)

```
neighbors :: (a, [a]) -> [(a, [a])]
neighbors (_, xs) = go [] xs where
    go ls [] = []
    go ls (r:rs) = (r, ls ++ rs) : go (r:ls) rs
```

We can now call the `aStar` search method with appropriate parameters. We'll use `([a], [[a]])` -- representing the current list of digits and the remaining lists that we can choose from -- as our node type. The arguments to `aStar` are then, in order: the function for finding neighboring nodes, the function for computing distance between neighboring nodes, the heuristic for how far we have left to go (we'll just say `1` for each unique element in the list), whether we've reached a goal node, and the initial node to start the search from. We'll call `fromJust`, but it should be okay: all nodes have at least one path to a goal node, just by choosing the remaining lists of digits in order.

```
optimal :: (Eq a, Ord a, Hashable a) => [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
optimal here elsewhere = (here:) . map fst . fromJust $ aStar
    (HS.fromList . neighbors)
    (\(x, _) (y, _) -> distance x y)
    (\(x, xs) -> HS.size (HS.fromList (x:xs)) - 1)
    (\(_, xs) -> null xs)
    (here, elsewhere)
```

Let's see it run in ghci:

```
> optimal sampleStart sampleNeighbors
["2222","1222","8822","8881","8888","5428","2221","2234"]
```

We can see that it's done better this time by adding a `pathLength` function that computes all the distances between neighbors in a result.

```
pathLength :: Eq a => [[a]] -> Int
pathLength xs = sum [distance x y | x:y:_ <- tails xs]
```

In ghci:

```
> pathLength (greedy sampleStart sampleNeighbors)
15
> pathLength (optimal sampleStart sampleNeighbors)
14
```

In this particular example, I think the greedy algorithm *could* have found the optimal path if it had made the "right" choices whenever there were ties for minimal next step; but I expect it is not too hard to cook up an example where the greedy algorithm is forced into bad early choices.